# Server emails are considered as SPAM only by Gmail

Tags: email, spam, gmail

I'm developping a service which lets users send our content via email to their friends. The problem is that those emails often ended up as Spam. So I went through all the stuff to make my server send nice emails with correct headers (SPF, DKIM, rDNS, etc...).

Now the emails have clean headers, and are being received fine by hotmail or yahoo, but are still being marked as spam in Gmail ! I am going completely crazy over this, since I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. The welcome message when a user subscribes has almost the same template, and yet is not considered as Spam...

Here is a sample of the headers (where I've hidden IPs and the domain):

```
Delivered-To: testxxxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.68.217.163 with SMTP id oz3csp61408pbc;
        Thu, 17 Jan 2013 05:07:39 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.194.172.228 with SMTP id bf4mr8314430wjc.38.1358428059148;
        Thu, 17 Jan 2013 05:07:39 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <anonymous@mail.mydomain.com>
Received: from mail.mydomain.com (mail.mydomain.com. [37.XX.XX.150])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id wp9si543337wjb.22.2013.01.17.05.07.38
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Thu, 17 Jan 2013 05:07:39 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of anonymous@mail.mydomain.com designates 37.XX.XX.150 as permitted sender) client-ip=37.XX.XX.150;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of anonymous@mail.mydomain.com designates 37.XX.XX.150 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=anonymous@mail.mydomain.com
Received: (qmail 22048 invoked by uid 502); 17 Jan 2013 14:07:38 +0100
Date: 17 Jan 2013 14:07:38 +0100
Message-ID: <20130117130738.22045.qmail@mail.mydomain.com>
To: testxxxx@gmail.com
Subject: Carlos t'as envoyÃ© un Cut
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 10000:functions.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="Multipart_NextPart-9004e0d0de3def8e547ef1c1218c9aab"
From: Carlos sur Service <noreply@mydomain.com>
Reply-To: Carlos <chaXXXlo@me.com>
```

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot in advance !

PS:

I use 2 images in the html, 2 links which points to mydomain.com, 2 social links and a bit of text. I used a template found on http://www.zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates

Comment: Gmail currently has a reason it spamboxes messages - when you open the email it says why at the top. What reason does it give you? If you have one like "similar content" then it can probably be fixed. If you have one like "emails from mydomain.com are known to be spam" then you need to worry about more than just the content of your messages.

Comment: It is the "Similar content as ..." message. So how can I find what is causing it, because all the online tests I've done gave me a good rating... And it is odd because I do receive the welcome message in the inbox, which has very similar content... I've made different versions with less images, more text, but in vain... Thanks for your help !

Comment: not sure if this is the cause for being flagged as spam by gmail but your subject header looks like it isn't properly encoded for non-ASCII characters. see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047